# Не активна ссылка в заголовке меню-аккордеон

Tags: jquery, php

Всем приветы! Бьюсь с кодом меню-аккордеон, но никак не получается сделать активной родительскую ссылку. Подменю открывается, но хотелось бы, чтобы при этом и родительская ссылка срабатывала. Привожу код:

Код PHP

```
<ul class="showHide">
    <li><?php
            $categories = get_cat1();
            foreach($categories as $item):
            ?>
            <a class="headli" href="index.php?view=cat&id=<?=$item['cat_id'];?>"><span><?=$item['name'];?></span>

            <?php endforeach;?> </a> 
      <ul >

          <li> <?php
            $categories = get_cat4();
            foreach($categories as $item):
            ?>

            <a href="index.php?view=cat&id=<?=$item['cat_id'];?>"><span><?=$item['name'];?></span>

            <?php endforeach;?>  </a></li>

          <li> <?php
            $categories = get_cat5();
            foreach($categories as $item):
            ?>

            <a href="index.php?view=cat&id=<?=$item['cat_id'];?>"><span><?=$item['name'];?></span>

            <?php endforeach;?> </a></li>

           <li><?php
            $categories = get_cat6();
            foreach($categories as $item):
            ?>

            <a href="index.php?view=cat&id=<?=$item['cat_id'];?>"><span><?=$item['name'];?></span>

            <?php endforeach;?>  </a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
      </ul>
```

Код JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var openItem = false;
        if($.cookie("openItem") && $.cookie("openItem") != 'false'){
            var openItem = parseInt($.cookie("openItem"));
        }
        $(".showHide").accordion ({
            active: openItem,
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false

        });

        $(".showHide .headli").click(function(){
            $.cookie("openItem", $(".showHide").accordion("option", "active") ,{expires: 7, path: "/" });
        });
    });
```

Пробовал вставлять navigation:true, но ничего не получается........

Что нужно поменять, вставить?

Заранее благодрарю!

Comment: Люди добрые, совсем никак.....????

Comment: Никто не может подсказать....  Жаль...